# How do I solve $y=x+B\sin(x+A)$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry, roots, inverse-function, newton-raphson, bisection

I have a code that converts x into y using the formula:
$y=x+B\sin(x+A)$

with $x, A$ and $B$ known values. $B$ is also very small so that $B\sin(x+A) < 0.035$.

The problem is that in another system I need to revert this operation. So given y, I need to get the original x.

I tried to do:
$n=y-B\sin(y+A)$

which provides a good approximation (since y is close to x) but I was wondering if there is a way to get the exact value so that n==x.

I also tried wolframalpha but it didn't help.

Comment: Are all angles and parameters expressed in degrees ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust all calculation I do are in radians. I only used degrees to demonstrate that $B sin(x+A)$ was very small (less than 2 deg).

Comment: Do you mean less than $0.035$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of $a$ with 
$$y+a=x+a+b\sin(x+a)$$

which is

$$y=x+b\sin(x)$$

after redefinition of the variables.

As $b$ is tiny (in fact it suffices that $|b|<1$), the RHS is monotonic and there is a single solution

$$x\approx y.$$

You can refine it by Newton, and the next approximation is

$$x\approx y-\frac{b\sin(y)}{1+b\cos(y)}.$$

Comment: +1, very clever to eliminate $a$ like this

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: Just tried:
$x ≈ y - (b*sin(y+a))/(1+b*cos(y+a))$

And the error was smaller than 2e-6. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @AdrielJr: then with one more Newton iteration, you'll get a nearly perfect value.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is already good enough, almost the precision of the float variable that I am using which is 1e-7. I am more concerned about performance than this level of precision.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an analytic solution. the function seems 1-to-1 on the plots, have you considered programming a root-finder?

You use, for example, either Bisection or Newton's method to do so. It should converge quite fast.

---

**UPDATE**

Indeed, as pointed out by @Jakobian in the comment, since $|B| < 1$, we have
$$
f'(x) = 1 + B \cos(x+A) > 0
$$
hence the function is always increasing, and so must be 1-to-1, so there is a unique solution for the root finder to converge to.

Comment: If $|b|\leq 1$, the function is 1-1 (calculate derivative)

Comment: @Jakobian updated, thanks

Comment: Since the mapping is 1 to 1, I was thinking about mapping x values into y first, and then generate something like a LUT with the reverse mapping for each angle. It should be faster then using an iterative method.

Comment: @AdrielJr This will work, especially if you linearly interpolate in the middle with reasonably fine grained grid. But you will lose the precision if you need any points not in your original set (where you would have to interpolate).

Comment: It is probably ok since I can just increase the resolution of the table. I am more concerned about performance since this thing is in the hotspot of my algorithm and an iterative method would probably be too costly in terms of performance.

Comment: @AdrielJr Newton's method should converge *very* quickly given a good initial guess. I would start with approximating $x_0 \approx y$ and proceeding with Newton iterations, you should not need more than 3-4

Comment: @gt6989b I just tried using Yves approach and it worked. Probably not as fast as a LUT, but fast enough since I only needed 1 iteration. Thanks for your help!